# laravel two foreach in controller not working

Tags: php, laravel

**my controller**

```
  $albums =Album::where('verified',1)->get();;
        foreach($albums as $key => $album){
            $tracks = Track::whereIn('id',$album->track_id)->where('verified',1)->get();
            foreach($tracks as $key => $track){
                $singers =Singers::whereIn('id',$track->singers_id)->pluck('singers_name');
                dd($track->track_title);
                }
        }
```

Here $track get 2 data but second foreach dd($track->track_title) show only one data

Comment: Correct, you "dump and die" (dd) with an attribute of one $track.
What do you expect?

Comment: Use `dump()` instead of `dd()` if you want your script to continue running. (And maybe use a different key name (`$key2`) in your second loop)

Comment: Documentation: [Laravel: dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-dd). Applies to older Laravel versions as well.

Answer (score 0):

dd means dump and die, so it will just show first value and then exit the code.

use

Like below -

```
$albums =Album::where('verified',1)->get();;
        foreach($albums as $key => $album){


            $tracks = Track::whereIn('id',$album->track_id)->where('verified',1)->get();

            foreach($tracks as $key => $track){
                $singers =Singers::whereIn('id',$track->singers_id)->pluck('singers_name');
                print_R($track->track_title);
    
                }
die;
           

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong veribale to fetch Track: Follow the Step

```
 $albums =Album::where('verified',1)->get();
        foreach($albums as $album){
            $tracks = Track::whereIn('id',$album->track_id)->where('verified',1)->get();
            foreach($tracks as $track){
                $singers =Singers::whereIn('id',$track->singers_id)->pluck('singers_name');
                dd($track->track_title);
                }
        }
```